# Embedding SharePoint Pages

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to embed a SharePoint page using the Page Viewer Web Part (or some other method I haven’t thought of) without the Chrome?  I want to embed JUST the content within the Page Layout section in the diagram below)? It looks incredibly goofy if I embed a SharePoint page within a SharePoint page as it pulls in all the SharePoint Chrome from the Master Page.

[image: SharePoint Master Pages]
<sub>(source: [cleverworkarounds.com](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/100807-0504-sharepointb1.gif))</sub>

Comment: This question is here for historical reasons, but future questions like it should be asked on our sister site [sharepoint.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the PVWP is pretty simplistic, and cannot do something like this. It just displays whatever URL you give it.

An alternative I have used in the past is to put the content ("page layout" from your diagram) into a [minimal master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa660698.aspx), then include that using PVWP wherever the content is needed. This can get ugly if you have a lot of pages you are including like this, but it works.